# GradleBuild changes path for invoked tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

In my root build.gradle, I've defined a GradleBuild task like this:

```
project.task('distribute', type : GradleBuild) {

    startParameter = gradle.startParameter.newInstance()
    tasks = [":subprojectA:displayInfo"]
}
```

Given that my root project directory called root,
when I run the distribute task, the task that is executed is

```
:root:subProjectA:displayInfo
```

How is it that root becomes what looks like a subproject and why does the gradle build task not execute the correct task like this:

```
:subProjectA:displayInfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not an issue. Even though the gradle output indicates that root is a subproject, the correct task is still executed.